# Excel VBA alteration for MAC

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have the following Script which works perfectly in a windows environment. Upon saving the excel file it will open the assigned word document, update the links and then save it as a PDF in the same folder named off the C6 cell contents. Unfortunately, I need it to work on a MAC as well. I changed the path from "c:\Prop" to "/Prop/" (I created a folder on the root of the mac HD called Prop) and it works up to the point where is opens word, but then I get an unsupported function message... anyone know what the different function is for MAC office 16???

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim objWord, objWordDoc, objField As Object
    Dim boolSuccess, boolUpdated As Boolean
    Dim strFolderPath, strWordFileName, strPdfFileName, strOutput As String

    strFolderPath = "c:\Prop\"
    strWordFileName = "Prop.docm"
    strPdfFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(6, 3).Value & ".pdf"
    strOutput = "There are problems with updating the next fields:" & vbCrLf
    boolSuccess = True

    On Error GoTo Error
        Err.Clear

        Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        Set objWordDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(strFolderPath & strWordFileName)

        If Not objWordDoc Is Nothing Then
            For Each objField In objWordDoc.Fields
                boolUpdated = objField.Update
               If Not boolUpdated Then
                    boolSuccess = False
                    strOutput = strOutput & "Field" & CStr(objField.Index) & vbCrLf
                End If
            Next
            objWordDoc.Save
            objWordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat strFolderPath & strPdfFileName, 17
            objWordDoc.Close
            If boolSuccess Then
                MsgBox strWordFileName & " was updated successfully and " & strPdfFileName & " was saved in " & strFolderPath
            Else
                MsgBox strOutput
                MsgBox strWordFileName & " was updated with problems and " & strPdfFileName & " was saved in " & strFolderPath
            End If
        End If
Error:
    If Err.Description <> "" Then
        MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description, , "Error"
    End If

    objWord.Quit

    Set objWordDoc = Nothing
    Set objWord = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The `CreateObject` function is part of the Windows scripting library, it doesn't exist on Mac OSX.

You should have more luck by referencing the `Microsoft Word Object (v.x.x) Library` (tools -> References) and not creating the object at runtime:

```
dim objWord as New Word.Application
dim objWordDoc as Word.Document
Set objWordDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(strFolderPath & strWordFileName)
```

This way you are not relying on the windows libraries.

Answer (score 0):

CreateObject works fine with me on mac with office 2011... I think the problem is the path string. On mac paths are different. I believe it should be something like this:

"OSX:Local:Prop:Prop.docm" or if you want it separated:

```
strFolderPath = "OSX:Local:Prop:"
strWordFileName = "Prop.docm"
```

Tell me if it worked :)