# Regular Expression library missing in excel VBA for Mac

Tags: regex, excel, vba, activex

I know this question have been asked several time in different form but I have tried several ways to solve this issue but not getting any that could help me.

The main problem is that I have an Excel VBA Userform that throws error of the following kind for Mac user :

"

```
Run_Time error '429': ActiveX Component Cant't Create Object
```

"

I tried several solutions like:

1.Adding Reference of Regular Expression since my code uses regex. But on going through various pages, I found that Microsoft vbscript regular expressions object library doesn't exists for Mac.

So I followed this link which asked me to download .pkg file and add it to the VBA library but this showed error like "This file is not supported".
[RegEx with Excel VBA on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344932/regex-with-excel-vba-on-mac)

2.Replacing CreateObject

I followed this link [Excel VBA alteration for MAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291781/excel-vba-alteration-for-mac)

Replaced **Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")** with **Dim regex As New VBScript.RegExp**

(THIS TOO DIDN'T WORKED)

The error causing code:

```
Dim edi_ec, edi_doc, method_implement, van As String
Dim Situacao As String
Dim regex As Object
**Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")**  // THIS LINE //
```

COMPLETE CODE :

```
Dim edi_ec, edi_doc, method_implement, van As String
Dim Situacao As String
Dim regex As Object
Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

'Checking the 1st four fields
If TextBox1.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Company Name Cannot be empty"
TextBox1.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If


'1. EDI/EC profiles checkboxes conversion to string
edi_ec = ""
If CheckBox1 = True Then
    edi_ec = "Edifact"
End If
If CheckBox2 = True Then
    If edi_ec = "" Then
        edi_ec = "ANSI X12"
    Else
        edi_ec = edi_ec & ", ANSI X12"
    End If
End If


'2. list of documents
Dim trans_std_ver As String
trans_std_ver = ""
trans_std_ver = "Transaction Type 1 :" & Me.TextBox86.Value & " Version Used: " & Me.TextBox87.Value
If TextBox68.Visible = True Then
trans_std_ver = "Transaction Type 2: " & Me.TextBox68.Value & " Version Used: " & Me.TextBox75.Value
End If


'3 Value Added Network Provider
van = ""
If CheckBox25 = True Then
    van = "Sterling Commerce"
End If
If CheckBox26 = True Then
    If van = "" Then
        van = "GXS/Opentext (Edi Express, Tradent or TGMS)"
    Else
         van = van & ", GXS/Opentext (Edi Express, Tradent or TGMS)"
    End If
End If
If CheckBox27 = True Then
    If van = "" Then
        van = "Inovis"
    Else
         van = van & ", Inovis"
    End If
End If

'4. senders and receivers ID's and Qualifiers for TEST & PRODUCTION
Dim test, production As String
test = "TEST ID 1: " & Me.TextBox46a.Value & "   QUALIFIER: " & Me.TextBox47.Value
production = "PRODUCTION ID 1: " & Me.TextBox49.Value & "   QUALIFIER: " & Me.TextBox48.Value
If TextBox52.Visible = True Then
test = test & ", TEST ID 2: " & Me.TextBox52.Value & "   QUALIFIER: " & Me.TextBox53.Value
production = production & " PRODUCTION ID 2: " & Me.TextBox54.Value & "   QUALIFIER: " & Me.TextBox51.Value
End If


'5 Method of communication other than VAN
Dim van_other As String
van_other = ""
If CheckBox30 = True Then
    van_other = "AS2"
End If
If CheckBox31 = True Then
    If van_other = "" Then
        van_other = "FTP(S) / SFTP"
    Else
        van_other = van_other & ", FTP(S) / SFTP"
    End If
End If


Dim comment As String
If TextBox67.Value <> "" Then
comment = TextBox67.Value
End If
'feeding the data to the spreadsheet
RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.count
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
.Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 1).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 2).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 3).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 4).Value = edi_ec
'.Offset(RowCount, 5).Value = edi_doc
.Offset(RowCount, 5).Value = trans_std_ver
.Offset(RowCount, 6).Value = method_implement
.Offset(RowCount, 7).Value = van
.Offset(RowCount, 8).Value = test
.Offset(RowCount, 9).Value = production
.Offset(RowCount, 10).Value = van_other
.Offset(RowCount, 11).Value = comment
'.Offset(RowCount, 11).value = text
End With

'Clearing the contents of the form on clicking submit
Dim ctl As MSForms.Control

    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        Select Case TypeName(ctl)
            Case "TextBox"
                ctl.text = ""
            Case "CheckBox", "OptionButton", "ToggleButton"
                ctl.Value = False
            Case "ComboBox", "ListBox"
                ctl.ListIndex = -1
        End Select
    Next ctl

    Unload Me
End Sub
```

As stated I have tried all the possible ways  but ended up with no solution. Is there any way(consistent with both Windows and Mac) where Regex library can be called from within the program as I have to sent this Userform to some non-technical people who have no clue about all this except the userform?

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: That library doesn't exist on Mac - it's a Windows-only COM thing.  Difficult to make any suggestions for a work-around since your posted code doesn't actually use the regexp....   Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344932/regex-with-excel-vba-on-mac

Comment: ActiveX is not available on Mac. It's based on COM, which is also not available on Mac.

Comment: Thank You @TimWilliams for taking out you time to answer my question.I tried to install the .pkg file as mentioned in the link you posted but that too doesn't seem to solve my problem.

Comment: Thank you @KenWhite for answering. What could be the solution to this problem as I have tried a lot of them already but didn't got any to solve my problem.

Comment: You could show the actual task for which you want to use regexp - it's not always necessary.